# how to redirect java page without using jsp and servlet?

Tags: java, arrays, hibernate, swing, applet

i have create one login page through only java in hibernate. and i want to redirect new through java page without using jsp,servlet, html. only share information about code.

```
public static void LoginPage() {


    AnnotationConfiguration acfg= new AnnotationConfiguration().configure();
    SessionFactory factory= acfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session=factory.openSession();

    Query q=session.createQuery("from RegistrationPage_DTO");  
    List list=q.list();
    Iterator ite=list.iterator();

    while (ite.hasNext()) {
        RegistrationPage_DTO reg=(RegistrationPage_DTO)ite.next();

        if ((reg.getCompany_mail() !=null) && (reg.getCompany_pass() !=null)) {

            System.out.println("sucessfully login");
        }
    }

    session.close();
    factory.close();
```

Comment: Javascript is not JAVA, please fix the tags in your question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). As it stands, it is not very clear what you are asking in this question.